# How to upgrade Xcode 9 to Xcode 10.1 in mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1815)

Tags: mac, macos, xcode

I've an Early 2011 MacBook and I am not able to upgrade the operating system beyond macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1815) on it. I am working with Xcode and in my current project I need to integrate Auto-renewable Subscriptions functionality, but discount features such as free trail period, pay as you go, and pay upfront are linked in introductory pricing API class. This is available in Xcode 10, and I really needs to install it on my Mac, because iOS 12 and greater requires this feature in Auto-renewable Subscription modules in order to approve app from iTunes App Store team.

So anyone could help me install Xcode 10.1 or even Xcode 10 on my Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1815)?

Comment: There's no Mac that can run Sierra but not High Sierra. You're either blocked at El Capitan or High Sierra, depending on model. [& there is no MacBook early 2011, but there is a MacBook Pro... compatible with High Sierra.]

Comment: I am using MacBook pro early 2011. the problem is not operating system instead my problem is Xcode which does not support sierra.

Comment: Correct. So your solution is to upgrade to High Sierra.

Comment: how can i upgrade to high sierra. when there is no link for update in my app store.

Comment: You can Google for it - then you'll get this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10.1 is not supported in macOS Sierra. You’ll need macOS High Sierra it later to run Xcode 10.1.

Since your model of MacBook Pro supports running macOS High Sierra, it's recommended that you upgrade to it. You can install current latest version of Xcode 10.2 in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t update your OS then the only other solution I can think of would be to create a virtual machine, install Mojave and Xcode 10 in it, and do all of your development within the virtual machine.  It’s not ideal, but it is workable.